# Programacion de condicionales en EXCEL SI, SINO

Tags: excel, condiciones, excepciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buenas tardes, muchas gracias por ayudarme, tengo un problema y es que nunca he realizado if en excel y no tengo idea de como se realiza, tengo el siguiente problema;

SI el evento inicial es "despejado" entonces se compara el numero "random", si este menor de 0,8 la PREDICCION es "despejado" SINO la PREDICCION es "lluvia"

SI por el contrario el evento inicial es "lluvia" entonces se compara el numero "random" si este es menor de 0,6 la PREDICCION es "lluvioso" SINO la PREDICCION es "despejado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿qué has intentado hasta ahora? Por otro lado, la explicación me parece poco clara, ya que inmediatamente después de la condición del _si tal cosa entonces_, pones un _SINO_, y eso no tiene sentido... la construcción lógica es **_si tal cosa entonces X sino Y_**.

Comment: Por otro lado, pienso que lo que quieres es calcular el valor de la columna "predicción", pero tu redacción apunta a que hay casos en los que quieres cambiar el evento, lo que crearía una referencia circular...

Comment: Hola, disculpa por no expresarme bien, mira, todo arranca con evento inicial. si el evento es "despejado" puede pasar dos cosas, que el el numero random sea menor a 0,7, en ese caso seria PREDICCION "despejeado", de lo contrario seria "lluvioso". Luego por otro lado con el evento inicial "lluvioso" pueden pasar otras 2  cosas, si el numero random es menor a 0,6 la prediccion es "lluvioso", de lo contrario es "despejado"

Comment: no sé si así me hice explicar bien

Comment: Sugiero entonces que edites tu pregunta y mejores su redacción. Déjame un comentario cuando lo hayas hecho y con gusto te dejo una solución.

Comment: Voy a realizare un diagrama de flujo para mejorar eso, muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Gracias jachguate, amigo ya edité la pregunta

Answer (score 4):

Este sería la Fórmula:

```
=SI(Y(C3="despejado",D3<0.8),"despejado",SI(Y(C3="despejado",D3>=0.8),"LLuvia",SI(Y(C3="lluvia",D3<0.6),"lluvioso",SI(Y(C3="lluvia",D3>=0.6),"despejado"))))
```

[image]

Comment: Gracias, funcionó perfecto, de verdad mil gracias

Comment: @AndresPaez si esta respuesta te ayudó, por favor, márcala como correcta. [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes valerte de la función **[si](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/si-funci%C3%B3n-si-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)** de Excel para realizar la tarea. Esta función recibe tres parámetros:

- La condición a evaluar, que es una expresión que devuelve los valores `verdadero` o `falso`, por ejemplo una comparación.
- Una expresión que devuelve el valor a devolver si la condición se cumple
- Una expresión que devuelve el valor a devolver si la condición no se cumple (el si-no, o *de lo contrario*).

La buena noticia es que cada expresión puede ser una nueva llamada a una función, que es justo lo que necesitamos para encadenar varias evaluaciones `si`, tal como planteas.

Aprovechando que en la columna `B` solo aparecen dos valores, podemos hacerlo de manera simple así:

- Comparamos si el valor de la columna `B` es igual a `"despejado"`

  - Si es igual despejado, comparamos si el valor de la columna `C` es menor a `0.8`

    - Si lo es, devolvemos `"despejado"`
    - Si no lo es, devolvemos `"lluvia"`
  - si no es despejado, ya no hace falta comparar si es igual a `"lluvia"` (tiene que serlo, ya que no hay otro valor), entonces comparamos si el valor de la columna `C` es menor a `0.6`
  - Si lo es, devolvemos `"lluvioso"`
  - si no lo es, devolvemos `"despejado"`

Siguiendo esta lógica, la fórmula para la celda `D3` sería algo como:

```
=si(B3="despejado", si(C3<0.8, "despejado", "lluvia"), si(C3<0.6, "lluvioso", "despejado"))
```